# Expanding ListViewByQuery Web Part stuck on "Working on it..."

Tags: 2013, list-view, caml, list-view-web-part, grouping

I am using a `ListViewByQuery` in a custom web-part. If I set the CAML `GroupBy` to `<GroupBy Collapse='FALSE'>` (i.e. expanded), the webpart works fine. However, if I set it to `<GroupBy Collapse='TRUE'>`, the item will expand, but then is stuck/hangs on the "Working on it..." message:

[image]

(I believe the old message in SharePoint 2010 was "Loading...").

Here's the working copy when it's pre-expanded:

[image]

This doesn't appear to be a JavaScript issue (tested on multiple browsers).

How do I fix this?

---

Aside: Karine mentions a very similar issue on her blog using the `ListViewByQuery` Web Part [here](http://karinebosch.wordpress.com/sharepoint-controls/the-listviewbyquery-control/). I will test the suggested JavaScript fix and report back, but I believe this is only a workaround - what is the underlying cause and solution?

Update: I can't get the JS fix working. I'm dynamically generating the `ListViewByQuery` control in my custom webpart (as seemingly required) and while the JS seems to fire, I can't determine how to debug it.

Update 2: Finally got the JS fix working - the collapse was being called twice (so it would jsut expand again). Will suggest this as possible answer soon, but won't accept it as actual answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simply how I got the JavaScript fix/kludge working. Firstly, you must pre-expand the `ListViewByQuery` CAML group (`Collapse='FALSE'`). Secondly, the suggested JavaScript runs twice and simply collapses/expands the result, so it doesn't seem to work in 2013. So here's how I got working:

I create the `ListViewByQuery` control dynamically (as required/recommend in doco):

```
Panel pnlDiv = new Panel();
pnlDiv.ID = "pnlDiv";
pnlDiv.CssClass = "ms-authoringcontrols";

ListViewByQuery lvPdfs = new ListViewByQuery();

..

EnsureChildControls();

pnlDiv.Controls.Add(lvPdfs);
pnlDiv.RenderControl(writer);
RenderChildren(writer);
```

As I had trouble with JavaScript I emitted it server-side:

```
        private void RegisterExpandJavascriptFix()
        {
            ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

            if (!cs.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(this.GetType(), "CollapseFunc"))
            {
                cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "CollapseFunc", JSExpandFix, true);
            }

            if (!cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(this.GetType(), "Collapse"))
            {
                cs.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CollapseFunc", "collapseDiv();", true);
            }
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                RegisterExpandJavascriptFix();
            }
        }
```

And here's the JavaScript:

```
private const string JSExpandFix = @"function collapseDiv() {                                                    
                                                    var div = document.getElementById('pnlDiv');
                                                    //alert(div);
                                                    if (div != null) {
                                                        var links = div.getElementsByTagName('a');
                                                        for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
                                                            if (links[i].href == 'javascript:' && links[i].onclick.toString().indexOf('ExpCollGroup') > -1 && links[i].previousSibling.tagName == 'IMG') {                                                                
                                                                //alert(links[i].onclick.toString());                    
                                                                links[i].click();
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }";
```

Note the `links[i].previousSibling.tagName == 'IMG')` check - this is just my way to ensure it only clicks the **first** collapse link (i.e. the plus/minus image, rather than the text).