# Sharepoint ListViewByQuery webpart Group By shows intermittent Working on it

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, list-view

My problem is very similar to this thread : [Expanding ListViewByQuery Web Part stuck on "Working on it..."](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/92807/expanding-listviewbyquery-web-part-stuck-on-working-on-it)

But, in my case the issue only occurs if I use some other custom component that also uses javascript. When i remove that component, the group by can collapse and expand properly.

I also noticed that when I set the Group By to Expanded, the issue also disappears.

[Update] I noticed that when the javascript goes to ExpGroup function, there is an element called tabTb.clvp which is 'undefined'. This will call the function to return and the row is not expanded then....

```
function ExpGroup(evt, groupName) {
    var tabBody = document.getElementById("tbod" + groupName + "_");

    if (tabBody != null) {
        var tabTb = GetAncestor(tabBody, "TABLE");
    }

    if (tabBody == null || tabBody.tagName != "TBODY" || tabTb == null || typeof tabTb.clvp == "undefined" || tabTb.clvp == null || tabBody.getAttribute("isLoaded") == null)
        return;
    var viewCounter = groupName.substring(0, groupName.indexOf("-"));
    var lookupEntry = document.getElementById("GroupByCol" + viewCounter);
    var queryString = "?";

    if (lookupEntry != null) {
        queryString = lookupEntry.getAttribute("queryString");
        if (queryString.substring(queryString.length - 1) == "&")
            queryString = queryString.substr(0, queryString.length - 1);
    }
    queryString = RemoveOnlyPagingArgs(queryString);
    queryString += "&GroupString=";
    queryString += ExpGroupFetchGroupString(groupName);
    queryString += "&IsGroupRender=TRUE";
    var tabTbClvp = tabTb.clvp;

    tabTbClvp.tBody = tabBody;
    tabTbClvp.RefreshPaging(queryString, null);
}
```

No idea what that element is and why it is 'undefined'

Not very sure why this problem would occur...any ideaS?

Answer (score 0):

The top bets on why would be a shared namespace or the script you removed is loading something prematurely, but the only way to know for sure is to load the page using your browser's developer console and look at the Javascript tab.

Comment: Kind of a newb to javascript, how would i do that exactly? thanks

Comment: In most modern browsers, go to the page you're working with and press F12 to open up the Dev Console. In IE there's a tab marked Console (varies in other browsers, but similar) where you'll find script errors popping up if there are any. If you're not sure if some code is being loaded or how far into your code something is going, you can always use the cheap but reliable method of    alert("Hello World");   If that doesn't pop up, things aren't loading up/running to that point.

Enjoy the crash course in debugging. :)

Comment: Thanks Graham! But I am not getting any javascript errors.....

Comment: Alright then you're going to want to use the alert code. Somewhere, code is either not being called or is being called in the wrong order.